# I'm trying to use strcat inside while loop of strtok, but it resulted in segmentation fault

Tags: c

I'm trying to get rid of the white spaces in string str and put the words in char* no_blank, but it keeps resulting in segmentation fault. Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "geeks     for    Geeks";
    char* no_blank =malloc(strlen(str)+1);
    no_blank[0] = 0;
    // Returns first token
    char* token = strtok(str, " ");
    strcat(no_blank,token);
    printf("%s\n", no_blank);
    // Keep printing tokens while one of the
    // delimiters present in str[].
    while (token != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        strcat(no_blank," ");
        strcat(no_blank,token);
    }
    printf("%s\n", no_blank);
    free(no_blank);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values?

Comment: Yeah I did. I figured it out lol Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, inside the `while` loop, when the `strtok()` returns a NULL, you're still trying to use that as argument to `strcat()`, as in

```
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");  // when token in NULL
    strcat(no_blank," ");
    strcat(no_blank,token);      // you're still using it.
```

You need to ensure that the token returned by `strtok()` is a valid one, before you make use of that.